# how do I install realvnc-vnc-server on Ubuntu linux Groovy?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, realvnc, groovy

Installing real-vnc-vncserver from deb file downloaded from Realvnc.com fails due to missing a dependency. This seems to be missing libgcc1 which is not available on Groovy (20.10)

There is a libgcc-s1. Is this the same thing and how do I tell the installer to use it ? or is there another way ?
The server seems no longer to be available from Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt` or `gdebi` to instal the `*.deb` package. `libgcc1` isn't available for ubuntu 20.10.

```
sudo apt install gcc-10-base gdebi gdebi-core
wget https://www.realvnc.com/download/file/vnc.files/VNC-Server-6.7.2-Linux-x64.deb
sudo gdebi VNC-Server-6.7.2-Linux-x64.deb
```